# i have 2 model schema, userSchema and courseSchema

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to fetch the user's `firstName` and `lastName` if they are already enrolled on my `courseSchema`?

---

#### courseSchema

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Course Name is required"]
        },
        description:{
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Enter description"]
        },
        price:{
            type: Number,
            required: [true, "Enter a Number"]
        },
        isActive:{
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        },
        createdOn:{
            type: Date,
            default: new Date
        },
        enrollees:[
        {
            userId:{
            type: String,
            required: [true, "Enter Enrollee"]
            },
            enrolledOn:{
            type: Date,
            default: new Date
            }
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have another collection for your users which contains the same `userId` as you have in your `enrollees` array, you can perform a `$lookup` operation to perform a join between the two collections to retrieve the users' first and last names.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/